# webpack-cli can't find webpack module

Tags: npm, webpack

i have installed webpack globally and when i run `webpack` it says

```
One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no):
```

and I say yes, the webpack-cli seems to be installed correctly but i got an error message that says

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:7:24)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at yargs.parse (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:228:14)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:206:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:505:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at runCommand.then (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:143:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

what is possibility goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `npm link webpack-cli` to Link Globally installed package of your project